# Java opencv robinson mask, Image is completely black

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I was playing around with open cv and I decided to test out tutorialpoint's [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_dip/applying_robinson_operator.htm) for a Robinson mask. I copied the code and used a grayscaled jpg.

 -unfortunately the outputed image was completely black.

 -I tried commenting out what appears to be two additional directional filters. The image still came out black.

-I'm using java 1.8 with opencv 3

```
try{
     int kernelSize = 9;
     System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
     Mat source = Imgcodecs.imread("grayScale2.jpg",  Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
     Mat destination = new Mat(source.rows(),source.cols(),source.type());  
     Mat kernel = new Mat(kernelSize,kernelSize, CvType.CV_32F){
        {
           put(0,0,-1);
           put(0,1,0);
           put(0,2,1);

           put(1,0-2);
           put(1,1,0);
           put(1,2,2);

           put(2,0,-1);
           put(2,1,0);
           put(2,2,1);
        }
     };       

     Imgproc.filter2D(source, destination, -1, kernel);
     Imgcodecs.imwrite("robinsonMaskExample.jpg", destination);

  } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }
```

Comment: What does your image look like?  Did you try using the grayscale image in the post to see if the code worked?  I suspect that it has something to do with your input image, but I can't verify that unless I see it.  You don't have enough reputation to post an image, so post it on a public image website somewhere, like http://postimg.org and link us to it in your post.  One of us (perhaps me) will embed the image into your post.

Comment: Here is the [image I used](http://s15.postimg.org/dp8lpyzaj/gray_Scale2.jpg). also, the original image is still black

Comment: You also shouldn't comment out those two lines.  This is defining a 3 x 3 kernel and each line defines a coefficient in the mask.  What's happening here is that you are making the central column and right column 0 and so it isn't going to give you what you expect... then again, it looks like you tried the full 3 x 3 already and it isn't giving you anything.... besides which, I think I know what's going on.  One moment.  I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you linked us is a bit flawed.  It defines the kernel size to be size 9 x 9, but the kernel itself is clearly 3 x 3.  As such, it's putting the kernel coefficients at the top left corner of the kernel and the rest of the kernel itself is 0.  This is probably the reason why you're not seeing the right results.  The [`put`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#put(int,%20int,%20double...)) method puts a number in the row and column of the matrix.  As you can see in that code that defines the kernel, it's putting things in rows 0,1,2 and columns 0,1,2 - which is implicitly a 3 x 3 kernel, but the size of the kernel is actually 9 x 9.

As such, please **uncomment** those lines you commented out as it's important to define the entire edge detection mask properly.  Also, the post is wrong in terms of what edge detection mask that's using.  That's actually using the [Sobel operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator).  I've never heard of a mask called "Robinson" before, but I have heard of a [Roberts-Cross](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roberts_cross) mask, which is a **2 x 2** kernel that looks like this:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roberts_cross)</sup>

Therefore, the simplest fix is to change the kernel size so that it's 3.... so simply change this:

```
int kernelSize = 9;
```

To this:

```
int kernelSize = 3;
```

For a broader picture:

```
try{
     int kernelSize = 3; // Change
     System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
     Mat source = Imgcodecs.imread("grayScale2.jpg",  Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
     Mat destination = new Mat(source.rows(),source.cols(),source.type());  
     Mat kernel = new Mat(kernelSize,kernelSize, CvType.CV_32F){
        {
           put(0,0,-1);
           put(0,1,0);
           put(0,2,1);

           put(1,0-2);          
           put(1,1,0);
           put(1,2,2);

           put(2,0,-1);
           put(2,1,0);
           put(2,2,1); // Leave it this way - don't uncomment
        }
     };       

     Imgproc.filter2D(source, destination, -1, kernel);
     Imgcodecs.imwrite("robinsonMaskExample.jpg", destination);

  } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }
```

---

Moral of this story.  Let this be a lesson to you in terms of finding tutorials online.  Don't trust all of them, as they sometimes give you wrong information, such as what you experienced just now with the wrong kernel size and calling the edge detector wrong.  I'd certainly use them as a good starting point, but when it comes to the nitty-gritty details, always debug code that you see that has been posted to make sure that what they intended to write is actually what is produced.

Comment: @lleontan - No problem at all :) If I helped you, consider accepting my answer to let the StackOverflow community know you no longer need help in this regard.  That can be done by clicking on the checkmark icon at the top of my post, to the left below the up and down voting arrows.  Good luck!